# How to take database backup form WSO2 Stratoes Live Data Services Server

Tags: database, wso2, backup, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-stratos

I have created database on the Stratoes live server and my databse URL is this.
jdbc:mysql://rss1.stratoslive.wso2.com/karshamarkuptool_karsha_opensource_lk

I tried `Database Console> Tools> Back Up` and it asking me these credentials

> Target file name:~/backup.zip      Source directory:
>   jdbc:mysql://rss1.stratoslive.wso2.com/karshamarkuptool_karsha_opensource_lk
>   Source database name: karshamarkuptool_karsha_opensource_lk

Are my credentials right? it says there is no database found on the source directory.

If not what is the way to get a backup from Stratoes database? How can I configure it to get automatic weekly backup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have mysql installed in your local setup, you can get a backup as just as the same way that you would take a backup of a database that resides in your local database server. For example, the following command would get you a backup of your database that you created under the RSS manager of StratosLive Data Service Server.

> mysqldump -u your_username -pyour_password -h rss1.stratoslive.wso2.com extracted_host_name_from_the_JDBC_url_given_to_you database_name > local_file_system_path/backup.sql

Cheers,
Prabath